# how to solve this difficult Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on excel file, I have 2 columns A and B, I've set the value of B to this statement =IF(A1=1,NOW(),"") and every thing is going well, when I write 1 B will equal to Current Date, and if write anything else B will equal to nothing,

the problem is:- every time I set A to 1 the values for B column will change to the current date, I want only the current B for example B5 to change to current date not all Bs.

so can anyone help me...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "current B"?

Comment: By default, Excel does that, as well as with rand(), or similar functions.. Maybe this can help http://excel.tips.net/T003116_Recording_a_Data_Entry_Time.html

Comment: I mean Current Cell for B, for example I reach up to B22, when I type in A22 value 1 the B1-B22 will equal to current date, I just want to keep the old values for previous Bs and set the B22 to current date, how can I do that ???

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a timestamp for when the cell in column "A" had data written into it. If so, you may want to try a VBA trigger on the worksheet. Please try pasting the below code into the worksheet you want to target. ( Alt-F11 when excel is open, then double click the relevant worksheet )

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
End If
End Sub
```

If you truly want the timestamp in column B to generate **ONLY** when the value in column A is set to a numeric value of 1, then substitute the second line of code with this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Target.Value = 1 Then
```

You will not be able to get the `=NOW()` formula to stop showing the current system date & time whenever the workbook re-calculates without copy-pasting only the value from that cell manually & overwriting the formula ( what @pnuts suggested in the comments ) . I hope this vba workaround is what you need, though!